# Which preposition is very common with Disappointed with or by or in?

Tags: prepositions

> We enjoyed our holiday, but we were a bit disappointed **(with/by/in)** the
>   hotel?

Which preposition fits better here?

Comment: Please consider showing the results of your research. Some answers were suggested in this [English Language Learners SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22990/is-it-disappointed-with-in-or-by).

Comment: There was also [this ELU question: disappointed in versus disappointed with](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41679/disappointed-in-versus-disappointed-with).

Answer (score 1):

We tend to use "disappointed *in*" when speaking on a personal level about an individual or a group of people. It points to being disappointed by their character, commitment, or attitude which may have been revealed by an action, rather than the specific action itself.

We use "disappointed *by*" when referring to specific details or things which have caused us to be disappointed.

So, for example, we might say:

> I'm very disappointed *by* this hotel.

BUT:

> I'm very disappointed *in* the hotel management.